# What is the difference between UDP hole punching and STUN?

Tags: networking, router, internet, nat, udp

As the title says, what is the difference between UDP hole punching and STUN?

Or is it the same?

Comment: No, they are different, but it would probably be easier to read the two wikipedia articles, than it have it explained here.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/STUN http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UDP_hole_punching

Comment: Please open this question. It's a clear question as these two are very similar but I guess somehow different

Comment: STUN is a protocol implementing hole punching

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't delete my answer as its accepted, but my answer is wrong.  Please ignore it.

hole punching and STUN are quite different things.

<strike>STUN will allow a system to work out what its external IP address is (if, as is common, it is located behind a NATing firewall or equivalent).  It is really of use where the IP address of the Internet connection is dynamically assigned.</strike>

[UDP] hole punching allows a mapping from a real world IP address to a specific box behind a NATing firewall - This is a security thing, but much more importantly required because of the 1:many relationship NAT introduces - so the NATing router needs to know which client to send the packet too.  [ For responses to regular traffic it keeps a lookup table of associations between the From IP, Dest IP and ports used (and related ports if its doing its job well) ]

Comment: Actually UDP hole punching is where a device behind a NAT sends a UDP datagram to a known endpoint in order that that endpoint learns the externally mapped IP:port associated with that client UDP port.  This is communicated to another peer, which attempts to send datagrams to the first peer using that IP:port as destination.  This assumes that that port will relay inbound traffic from any peer (called "cone NAT") - it doesn't work for symmetric NAT (which only processes response packets that match the peer IP and port).

Comment: My answer is wrong.  It should not have been upvoted or accepted.  (Unfortunately it appears I can't delete it as it has been accepted)